# Issue in Inserting and retrieveing document in MongoDB using C# for dynamic datatype fields

Tags: c#, mongodb

Issue in Inserting and retrieving document in MongoDB using C# for dynamic data-type fields.

I am trying to insert values to MongoDB. I have 10 fields with different data-types. For example.

Name 
age
gender
New-value (class data-type)
etc..

I want to insert all these 10 fields in to MongoDB. The problem is the field are not fixed. Next time 20 fileds wil come some times 5 may be more than that.

Due to this problem I cannot use a class and serialize the document. I am using an XML which will have the Field Name and Data type, so if any new fields are added I can add that to XML  without changing the Code.

So I need to Insert these fileds into MongoDB.

I tried this..

```
var collection= db.GetCollection("TableName");
```

(cannot use a class here to map the values - using a class for the 10 fields it works)

```
value = randomDataType value
```

I want to store it in MongoDB and later retrieve using the same datatype.

```
doc["FieldName"] = (object)value
collection.Insert(doc);
```

This is not working.

Can any one please help me in this ?

Comment: Use this instead: var collection= db.GetCollection<ParentCustomDataType>("TableName"); var ele = new ParentCustomDataType(); ele.FieldName = value; collection.Insert(ele);

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know this method ,  I cannot use class here because.I cannot create a class with fixed number of values, later it can change. When it changes I do-not want to change the code. So I use an XML to save the name and Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method for insert:

```
var elemDoc = BsonExtensionMethods.ToBsonDocument(value);
doc["filedName"] = elemDoc;
collection.Insert(doc);
```